# Regular Expression - Allowing enter key (java)

Tags: java, regex

In my web application, I want the user to enter only SELECT statements. I am using the following regex to validate the entry.

```
(^(?i)select.+)(\\w|\\W)
```

The above code makes sure the entry should start with SELECT and then a WHITESPACE
(Example: SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
But when the user have the 'ENTER' key while creating query, the regex fails.
So I want the REGEX to all 'ENTER' key. Can anyone please tell me the syntax for REGEX to allow the user to use 'ENTER' key in text area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small aside: Your code does nothing to ensure a whitespace after `SELECT` because the dot matches any character except newlines.

But now, to answer your question: You need the `(?s)` flag to allow the dot to also match newlines. Plus, you should use a `\s` token to assert the presence of whitespace. The trailing `(\w|\W)` is rather mysterious - it matches any character, too...

So I would suggest this:

```
"^(?is)select\\s.*"
```

or even

```
"^(?i)select\\s"
```

because that's already enough to check if the string starts with `SELECT<space>`.

Comment: +1 for the `?s`. Anchoring with `\A` and `\Z` seemed to work too, but this is much simpler.

Comment: @Keppil: `\A` and `\Z` mean the same as `^` and `$`, respectively, unless the `(?m)` (multiline) flag is set.